# Configuring WP-CLI on Windows 10

Tags: php, wp-cli

I've installed `php5-cli` using bash, but Wordpress is using XAMPP's PHP 7 install. I've added `/mnt/c/xampp/php` to the PATH, and I've explicitly used `export WP_CLI_PHP='/mnt/c/xampp/php'` in `.bashrc`.

But when I do `wp --info`, I get:

```
PHP binary:     /mnt/c/xampp/php/php.exe
PHP version:    5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22
php.ini used:   /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

`PHP binary` seems correct, but the last two variables refer to PHP 5.

Comment: Good question! But I think you should change your title to something like "WP-CLI on Windows 10 using WSL with Windows PHP/MySQL". But yes, what you are trying to do would be ideal! It would be great to be able to use Ubuntu / Bash where all the WP-CLI commands work properly, but have the ease of being able to use Windows based PHP/MySQL like that from XAMPP rather than having to install all those on your WSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figured out how to do this, and it's actually really easy to do! Which is awesome because I think it's a great simple way to work!

First up, you don't want to change the PATH for PHP in bash. So you'll want to remove that. Instead, what you are doing is using bash based PHP and MySQL, but connecting to your Windows MySQL (installed by XAMPP).

**Step 1:**

`sudo apt install mysql-client php-cli php-mysql`

**Step 2:**

Create a symlink in bash to your website files, so something like this:
`sudo ln -s /mnt/c/websites /var/www`

**Step 3:**

You need to connect to you MySQL db with an IP address, not localhost. So when creating your config do something like this:

`wp config create --dbname=wpdbname --dbuser=wpdbuser --dbpass=securepswd --dbhost=127.0.0.1`

If you want more info, I also wrote a [blog post](https://creativelogic.biz/blog/wp-cli-on-windows-with-wsl/) about this.